# MVC 5 - More than one entry point?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.1

The standard Mvc web application template in VS 2013 has:

In Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(myApp.Startup))]
```

and also in Global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    { //...
    }
}
```

May I know what the sequence of execution is and whether it is guanranteed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right about there being more than one entry point. You can even have more than one of OWIN startup classes.

As far as I know `Application_Start` in `Global.asax.cs` is always executed first. Though, I did not find any statement about this being guaranteed. Just play it safe and avoid introducing any race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in both methods and hit debug. The first that gets hit, is the first that is launched ;).

Comment: If they are on different threads, the outcome on one particular machine may not be always repeated elsewhere.

Comment: Why would they be on different threads? I know there is async support etc in the latest version but in the startup of the project I am pretty sure that there will be only 1 thread for it.